# PHPmotion V2 / new google api3 = video-embedder + mass video embedder dont work

Tags: youtube-api, phpmotion

My site is www.civiljutub.hu, which is an important site in Hungary (hungarian NGOs). I use phpmotion v2.

Me and my users can't now (from 06-05-2015) embed videos from YouTube. Video-embedder and mass video embedder don't work. Message is:

> https://youtube.com/devicesupport

What is the resolution?

When I try to embedding a video = http://i.ytimg.com/vi/UKY3scPIMd8/0.jpg

4 years ago has been inserted into the video from YouTube ONLY. The site is dead if the paste function not working. What can be done so I can re-insert videos from YouTube?

Answer (score 0):

PHPmotion's YouTube-related power tools may need to be updated to accommodate the recent YT API changes.  Try getting in touch with PHPmotion customer service at http://service.phpmotion.com.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13438793)

Comment: I may be missing your point, but the essential parts of the answer actually are included here...in spite of the first-glance appearance, this isn't a link-only answer.  YouTube changed their API, and since the power tools in question are encrypted by PHPmotion, Nádor can't do anything to fix them himself.  His only option is to get in touch with PHPmotion's customer service.